# Is it optimal to use Map of Map?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

I have data lets say about names of players of different sports team for different countries. What data structure should I use to store this dataset , if my queries would involve finding if particular player plays for a particular team of a country.

Which of the following is a better data structure and why ?

```
1) HashMap<Country, HashMap<Sport, HashSet<PlayerName>>>
```

OR

```
2)
class CountrySport{
String Country
String Sport
}
//override hashcode and equals methods

HashMap<CountrySport, HashSet<PlayerName>>
```

The lookup in both cases would be O(1) , then which is a better data structure in this case ?

Comment: I think you should have `id` for both your `CountrySport` class as well as `Player` class. Say both `id` are `long` type. Once you have it, create two HashMaps `HashMap<PlayerID,PlayerName>` and `HashMap<CountrySportID,PlayerID>`. Look up `PlayerID` by `CountrySportID` and from the `PlayerID`, you can look up `PlayerName`.

Comment: There are many choices. To say which is best, you must be more precise about exactly what the queries will be. So far it sounds like you want a player-team relation. An efficient way to store that is as a set of `<player_id, team_id>` pairs, where the ids are small integers. You can map the integers to string names, team country, etc, with simple arrays where the ids are indexes. The set could be a rectangular array, hash table, balanced tree, skip list, etc. The best choice depends on lots of things you haven't told us.